# How to print racket check-expect results in terminal

Tags: terminal, racket

I have the following racket code:

```
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define (square val)
  (* val val))

(check-expect (square 3) 9)
```

When I execute the script in DrRacket using the Beginning Student language, I get the following output in the application console (the view is called “Interactions” in DrRacket):

> The test passed!

When I execute the same script in the Terminal via `racket my_script.rkt` I do not see any output. I checked `racket --help` but I don’t see any viable option. How can I execute the script in the Terminal and have the same line printed out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me in both DrRacket and in the terminal:

```
#lang racket/base
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define (square val)
  (* val val))

(check-expect (square 3) 9)
(test)
```

and prints

```
The only test passed!
```

Note that had to add `(test)` to make this happen, both in DrRacket and on the command line, according to [this doc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html).

Comment: DrRacket should also require the `(test)` call.

Comment: It does, at least in 6.2.1.

Comment: Ok, got it. I had set “Beginning Student” as language definition in DrRacket and it gave me `The test passed!Both tests passed!` when I added `(test)` at the end of the script. I had also to remove `#lang racket/base` at the top. Now I’ve added back `#lang racket/base` at the top and set the language option to “Determine language from source” and everything works as expected.